# CSS: hanging ::before labels with different formatting

Tags: css

I want to have labels that mark groups of words, where:

- The label is to the left of the word group
- The words are enclosed in lines, the label is not
- The words are indented, the label is not

Here's something that produces the wrong formatting.  The left hand boundary is applied to the text generated by ::before, and indentation also is applied to the text generated by ::before. How can I fix that?

```css
div[role=s]::before {
  content: "s ";
}

div {
  border-left: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px inset lightgrey;  
  
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div role="s">
Peter and John
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using your existing markup, you could `absolute`ly position the label outside of the div.

```css
div[role=s]::before {
  content: "s ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%; top: 0;
  width: 1em;
}

div[role=s] {
  border-left: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px inset lightgrey;  
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div role="s">
Peter and John
</div>
```

Or if you can introduce a new element, you could put the border around the nested element, and use `flex` on the parent to make them a row.

```css
div[role=s]::before {
  content: "s ";
}

div[role=s] {
  display: flex;
}

div[role=s] > div {
  border-left: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px inset lightgrey;  
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div role="s">
  <div>Peter and John</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this really helps.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div[role=s]::before {
  content: "s";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
}

div {
  border-left: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px inset lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px inset lightgrey;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div role="s">
  Peter and John
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael and Michael!  This is helpful.